# Does Asus AIMesh require use of a cloud service?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, cloud, asus

Does [Asus AIMesh](https://www.asus.com/Microsite/AiMesh/US/) require use of a cloud service, and if so what features require this?

Obviously to access the internet the router will need an internet connection, but [some routers, such as TP-Link's Deco, require a cloud service to configure them or view reports](https://community.tp-link.com/en/home/kb/detail/412492), which I am trying to avoid.

Comment: No; It doesn’t.

Answer (score 1):

I have looked at
[AiMesh whole home mesh wifi system](https://www.asus.com/Microsite/AiMesh/nafr-fr/)
and the only mention of a cloud service that I found was:

> **Always-Up-to-Date Protection against Attacks**
>
> A step above standard firewalls, the commercial-grade intrusion
> prevention system (IPS) performs in-depth scans of inbound and
> outbound internet data to block all common attacks. Thanks to **Trend
> Micro data center on the cloud**, this AiProtection feature updates
> itself whenever a new patch is available, ensuring your protection is
> always up-to-date

My conclusion is that the internet is only used for the purpose
of updating the AiMesh software.

The "AI" label itself seems like a commercial hype, since self-update
does not require artificial intelligence.

Comment: @C.Ross: Tell me you have not forgotten your bounty, *again*.